# Android "android:inputType" overrides "android:digits" if you set it after "android:digits" (Bug?)

Tags: android, view

If I do the following:

```
et_user_input.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("123-+"));
et_user_input.setInputType((EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL));
```

Setting the inputType second overrides the digits I specified. This is quite a headache since I am using a custom compound view and I cannot control in which order the switch case triggers based on the attributes.

Here is a small snippet of my code:

```
public ValidationEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ValidationEditText);
    int count = typedArray.getIndexCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int attr = typedArray.getIndex(i);

            switch (attr) {
                case R.styleable.ValidationEditText_android_inputType:
                    LogUtil.a(getClass(), "Here1");
                    et_user_input.setInputType(typedArray.getInt(attr, EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL));
                    break;

                case R.styleable.ValidationEditText_android_digits:
                    LogUtil.a(getClass(), "Here2");
                    et_user_input.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(typedArray.getString(attr)));
                    break;
            }

        }
}
```

"Here2" always triggers first followed by "Here1" in the switch case.

Is this "overriding" effect the desired behaviour of Android or is it actually a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution, problem was in thing that DigitsKeyListener extends NumberKeyListener, that returns number inputType. So solution is

```
public class CustomDigitsKeyListener extends NumberKeyListener {

private char[] mAccepted;

public CustomDigitsKeyListener(char[] mAccepted) {
    this.mAccepted = mAccepted;
}

public CustomDigitsKeyListener() {
}

public static CustomDigitsKeyListener getInstance(String accepted){
    CustomDigitsKeyListener cust = new CustomDigitsKeyListener();
    cust.mAccepted = new char[accepted.length()];
    accepted.getChars(0, accepted.length(), cust.mAccepted, 0);
    return cust;
}

@Override
protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
    return mAccepted;
}

@Override
public int getInputType() {
    return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS;
}
}
```